# g++ when compile and link multiple files

Tags: c++, hyperlink, g++

I encounter g++ compile/link problem.
I want to implement a Dynamic Array.
I separated my class definition and implementation into "DArray.h" and "DArray.cpp" files.
And do test in "DArraytest.cpp" file within which contains a main functionn.

all there files are in same directory, and I use the following command to compile
g++ *.cpp

but it still gives me such link error
 /tmp/cc4tu73o.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
DArray.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to`std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
DArray.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccdHUZjJ.o: In function`main':
DArraytest.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `DArray<int>::DArray()'
DArraytest.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to`DArray::append(int const&)'
DArraytest.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `DArray<int>::append(int const&)'
DArraytest.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to`DArray::append(int const&)'
DArraytest.cpp:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `DArray<int>::append(int const&)'
DArraytest.cpp:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to`std::cout'
DArraytest.cpp:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
DArraytest.cpp:(.text+0xb0): undefined reference to`std::basic_ostream >& std::endl >(std::basic_ostream >&)'
DArraytest.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
DArraytest.cpp:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to`DArray::~DArray()'
DArraytest.cpp:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `DArray<int>::~DArray()'
/tmp/ccdHUZjJ.o: In function`__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
DArraytest.cpp:(.text+0x11d): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
DArraytest.cpp:(.text+0x134): undefined reference to`std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccdHUZjJ.o:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Can someone help me

Comment: It looks like you defined templates in a source file. Move them into the header: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide all the .cpp file names to g++.  To avoid this you can create a makefile which can automatically apply same compilation rule to all .cpp files